# How can I implement Gauge Widgets in odoo 10

Tags: widget, gauge

In the odoo version 8.0 there is inbuilt library of Gauge Widgets, but In the letest version of odoo 10.0  is that any library of GaugeWidgets?or How can I  implement Gaugewidget in odoo 10.0? please give me some suggesion.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to add any library. You have to just write widget="gauge" and in the option set max_field in xml. That's it.

`<field name="filed_you_want _To _indicate" widget="gauge" style="width:150px; height: 80px; cursor: pointer;" options="{'max_field': 'your_field_to _set_limit'}">  </field>`

hope that it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install "[Gauge Widget for Kanban](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/web_kanban_gauge/)" module in your odoo10.